# How to set vs2011's default macro like $(vcinstalldir)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros

when i load the vs2010 projects I notify that  Vcinstalldir is different for different vs2010 projects .

I want to know where and how can I set or change those macros value like Vcinstalldir .